# How to switch/pull/merge Git branch with case sensitive folder changes on a case insensitive file system OS?

Tags: git, macos

I want to change the case of some folders originally in camelCase, to follow a naming convention in flatcase.

I have set the git `config` file to `ignorecase = false`.

I have then renamed those folders, and committed and pushed the affected files. I see on github that on the old `master` branch, files are listed as `myFolder/myFile` in camelCase for example, while on my branch `myBranch` with the new changes, files are listed as `myfolder/myFile` in flatcase, which makes me think that the changes were successful.

However, due to being on the case insensitive file system Mac OS, when I try to switch back from `myBranch` to `master`, I get the error

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
myFolder/myFile
```

Per other suggestions in Stack Overflow, I have tried forcing the switch with
`git switch -f master`. It did switch to master, but it listed `myfolder/myFile` (flatcase) as an untracked file because the OS file system didn't update folder name to `myFolder` (camelCase) when switching to `master`, it was still `myfolder` (flatcase). Removing those untracked files does not work as git would then detect `myFolder` (camelCase) as being deleted.

How can I switch between those two branches ?
Similarly, how can my teammates pull my branch and merge it into theirs without encountering the same error ?

Comment: macOS's file-systems aren't case-insensitive, they're case-preserving. So at a minimum, you could `rm -rf` your git's working tree (except the `.git` directory, of course) and _then_ do a `git checkout` and it'll use the stored filename casing because it will have to recreate the files.

Comment: Ah yes thank you for the correction. I am looking for a solution that would be the least disruptive for colleagues that would want to pull my branch, and that sounds a bit inconvenient for them, especially if they need to switch between branches